# How to stop this message in logcat android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

When I run my app on my device I am continuously getting this message in logcat

```
E/android.hardware.sensors@2.0-service-mediatek:
```

what is the meaning of this message and how to stop this message from logcat

I filtered by `show only selected application` but then also message showing

[image]

Comment: are you filtering for your own application , or everything ? just change the dropdown to filter only for your own app, top right on the dropdown - show only selected application

Comment: yes I filtered by "show only selected application" then also this message showing